# rendering static files with node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following lines to serve my static content located in `/public`.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html')));
});
```

If I call `localhost:1337/`, it works. What do I have to do so it works if I type `localhost:1337/a/b`? I am missing something...

===========EDIT============================================================

Let's say I have a website with different views :

```
/ => index.html
/:user/about => user.html
```

The way I would do to render those pages is create a directory (public) where I'd have the following structure :

```
|-public
 |-css
 |-js
 |-index.html
 |-user.html
```

Then I would declare in my app.js the following lines :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/:user/about', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'user.html'));
})

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'));
})
```

That doesn't work, and it's not really clear what I should do to get it working.

Comment: It seems works well for you codes. any error shown in your console?

Comment: The css and js content isn't found. When I add /a/b in the path, it tries to get the css and js content from "http://localhost:1337/a/js/..." and same goes with the css (instead of http://localhost:1337/js/...)

Comment: Maybe it is better to use `app.get('/a/b', function() {...})` to replace `app.get('/*', function() {})`...

Comment: I mean app.get('a/b', function() { ... }) doesn't work

Comment: I edited my question to make it a bit more clear what I am trying to achieve